# Can 'Next Start' DNN Scehdule be edited manually

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

Hi
I am trying to change the Next Start of Schedule in DNN5.
I know it is possible to change the Time Lapse that would ultimately change the Next Start of the schedule.
But what i want do is to set the the schedule everyday at 12AM.
I could do it with 'Run Now' at 12AM and set the Time Lapse to '1 day', so that the system would set the Next Run everyday at 12. But it seems impratical to run it at 12AM.
Is there any other way to change the time of the Next Run?
Should I change it right in the databse: dnn_ScheduleHistory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look around at the scheduler, yes i think the only way to save you doing the run now, would be to manually add / update  the record in the Schedulehistory table

Post on the dnn forum confimring there is not currently a way to run things at a specificed time

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/108/postid/361875/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation =)